# Node SocketIo - Client not emitting?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having issues with Node SocketIo client not emitting data. So when the client connects in the index.html does log the "Connected This Is A Test", however it does not socket.emit('cool'), no errors nor does it seem to log on server.js. I'm not sure why its not emitting or the server isnt listening.

Server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

const PORT = 3002;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// run when client connects
io.on('connection', () => {
    console.log('New WS connection...');
    io.emit('connection', 'This Is A Test');
});

io.on('cool', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
});


server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
  socket.on('connection', function(data){
    console.log("connected", data);
    socket.emit('cool', 'MSG');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your server, you need to be listening for the `cool` message on a specific connected socket, not on the `io` object.  The `io` object does not have specific socket messages other than announcing a newly connected socket.  To listen for messages from a specific socket, you need a listener on the connected socket itself.  The usual place to add that listener is in the `connection` event where you are presented with the newly connected socket object.

So change this:

```
// run when client connects
io.on('connection', () => {
    console.log('New WS connection...');
    io.emit('connection', 'This Is A Test');
});

io.on('cool', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

to this:

```
// run when client connects
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New WS connection...');

    // send a test event back to the socket that just connected
    socket.emit('test', 'This Is A Test');

    // listen for the cool message on this new socket
    socket.on('cool', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
```

Also, you really should not be emitting event names used by the system like `connection`.  That's why I changed the event name to `test` so it won't conflict with names that socket.io itself is using.